# Fetching results from a method in Django

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

My Django app ('crisismode') has two models : Events and Actions

I would like to display events and actions related to these events. For each event, I only want to display active actions, so I used a method (activactions).

How to prefetch these actions ?

```
class Event(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def activeactions(self):
        actions = Action.objects.filter(event=self, active=True)
        if actions:
            return Action.objects.filter(event=self, active=True)
        else:
            return None

class Action(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="actionsforevent", null=True, blank=True)
```

I perform the following query:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(crisis=crisis, active=True).prefetch_related('actionsforevent')
```

But django-debug-toolbar shows me that there are multiple queries for it :

```
FROM "crisismode_action"
 WHERE ("crisismode_action"."active" = true AND "crisismode_action"."event_id" = 323)
 ORDER BY "crisismode_action"."order" ASC, "crisismode_action"."id"
 ASC 10 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Prefetch only those actions whose `active` field is `True`? (Also prefetch related would make multiple queries)

Comment: Yes, only those actions whose active field is True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would state a part from the documentation about [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

> **prefetch_related**, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python.

Meaning that prefetch related would make multiple queries. Moving on looking at your question you have a method `activeactions` in which you try to fetch the active actions for an event. Also you try using prefetch related as `.prefetch_related('actionsforevent')`. This does not work as you expect because the prefetching you do is separate from your method call. Also you don't filter in this prefetching.

For your use I believe you want to prefetch only the actions whose field `active` is `True`. You can do this using the [`Prefetch` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) which can take a queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

events = Event.objects.filter(
    crisis=crisis,
    active=True
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'actionsforevent',
        queryset=Action.objects.filter(active=True),
        to_attr='active_actions'
    )
)
```

We used the `to_attr` argument to specify that we wanted the results on a custom attribute `active_actions`.

Now we can simply access the prefetched active actions by using `event.active_actions`. e.g.:

```
for event in events:
    for action in event.active_actions:
        print(action.description)
```